# Duda sobre la notificación en los pagos recurrentes al finalizar el período de cobro

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy teniendo una duda la cual no puedo encontrarle una respuesta clara en ningún foro o comunidad de Mercado Pago, la situación es la siguiente, al elaborar un pago recurrente en el entorno productivo con usuarios de prueba pero con las credenciales de testeo que todavía no están homologadas, creo un pago recurrente con los siguientes parámetros:

```
$preapproval_data = array(
    "payer_email" => "test_user_****@*****.com",
    "back_url" => 'http://www.miurl.com/,
    "reason" => "Ejemplo",
    "external_reference" => "Numero de Referencia",
    "auto_recurring" => array(
        "frequency" => 1,
        "frequency_type" => "days",
        "transaction_amount" => "10",
        "currency_id" => "ID de la moneda",
        "start_date" => "fecha",
    )
  );
```

Una vez hecha la llamada API para crear el pago recurrente recibo sin problemas el pending antes de hacer el pago y el approved después de que el recurrente se realizó, ahora mi problema/duda es la siguiente al terminar ese período de 1 día que sería la expiración del pago, no estoy recibiendo ningún tipo de notificación por parte de MP de que el pago debe renovarse, entonces como me doy cuenta que esos pagos después de ese período siguen activos y se debitaron con éxito?

Otra de las cosas que estoy viendo es que tiempo después que se hizo ese pago recibo una llamada desde el IPN con el topic payment pero el status dice in_process y hace referencia a ese primer preapproval que se ha creado, que significa esto?

Bueno espero que alguien pueda sacarme de esta confusión.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te comento que hay 2 opciones para utilizar las suscripciones:

1. Realizar una suscripción recurrente, sin una fecha de vencimiento incluyendo todos los siguientes atributos a tu preferencia de pago:

   ```
   <?php
     $preapproval_data = array(
     "payer_email" => "my_customer@my-site.com",
     "back_url" => "http://www.my-site.com",
     "reason" => "Monthly subscription to premium package",
     "external_reference" => "OP-1234",
     "auto_recurring" => array(
           "frequency" => 1,
           "frequency_type" => "months",
           "transaction_amount" => 60,
           "currency_id" => "ARS"
       )
     );

   $preapproval = $mp->create_preapproval_payment($preapproval_data);
   ?>
   ```
2. Generar un pago recurrente con fecha de expiración que deseen, pero Mercado Pago no les enviara un mail indicando que finalizo la suscripción, eso es algo que deberían verificar internamente.

   ```
   {
    ...
    "auto_recurring": {
      ...
      "end_date" => "2018-12-10T14:58:11.778-03:00",
      ...
     },
   ...
   }
   ```

Saludos